# How to make asynchronous GET request on RAILS and only get view form (not whole body and headers)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, asynchronous

I created a simple asynchronous jquery function on my rails app so I can print the response on a "display" div. But when I make the GET request to my rails url it responds the whole html: "body", "head" and "includes" as if it were a new page on a browser, so the resulting source is the following:

Before I push the button:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Myapp1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <button onclick="callPage()">Call</button>
      <div id="display"></div>
  </body>
<html>
```

After I push the button and the "display" div is filled with my response:

```
<html>
      <head>
        <title>Myapp1</title>

      </head>
      <body>
          <button onclick="callPage()">Call</button>
          <div id="display">
             *<html>
               <head>
                 <title>Myapp1</title>
               </head>
               <body>
                 -----Content of page user/1 which is the only thing I want to get.------
               </body>
             <html>*
          </div>
      </body>
```

My route to users on routes.rb (RUBY ON RAILS) working fine

```
  resources :users
  #get 'welcome/index'
  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => :get
```

My Jquery GET callPage (working fine)

```
<script>
         function callPage()
    {   
        url="user/1";
        div="display";
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "text",
            url: url,
            success: function(msg){
                if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
                {
                    $("#"+div).html(msg);
                }
            }   
        }).setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', AUTH_TOKEN);
    }
        </script>
```

The question is how do I prevent RAILS from printing out every html tag all over (body, heads,...) and get it to print only the view of the controller I want (in this case, users). ¿Is it a configuration somewhere or do I wave to trim this off somehow?

Thanks a million in advance for your time.

Comment: don't you want JSON here and not html?

Comment: To only display the view you have to change your controller action to have `render layout: false` at the end. This will prevent the layout from rendering, leaving only the content in your view file.

Comment: Hello, what I want to do is display a form on a div asynchronously, I did not understand what JSON has to do with this. Thanks

Comment: @nbermudezs well that was fast!! Thanks man, solved it.

Comment: no problem, I've added it as an answer and showed the controller code just in case :). Feel free to mark it as accepted.

Comment: @nbermudezs not actually sure how to mark it as accepted, this is my first question

Comment: @FedericoRvg Check http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235, you have to hover over the answer upvote/downvote to see the accept icon, then just click it. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To only display the view you have to change your controller action to have render layout: false at the end. This will prevent the layout from rendering, leaving only the content in your view file.

For example:

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  def show
    # bla bla
    render 'your_show_view_name', layout: false
  end
end
```

If you want all your controller actions to have this behavior you can put it right at the top

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  layout false
  def show
    # bla bla
  end
end
```